# How to manage duplicate macro definitions with doxygen?

Tags: macros, duplicates, doxygen

The code I am working on is expected to run of different hardware plateforms.  Therefore, I use conditional compilation statements, depending on the hardware variant, into which macros are defined.

As a consequence, I have duplicate macro names.  This works fine as long as we consider only one definition can be used at a time.

However, I would like to group and duplicate the macros definitions into the doxygen output which is expected to showcase the hardware variants.

The source code is written in C and it looks similar to this:

```
/**
 * \def foo
 * \brief foo is oof
 *
 * \def bar
 * \brief bar is fool
 */
 #ifdef HW_A
 /**
 \addtogroup    HW_A
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#elif   HW_B
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_B
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#elif   HW_C
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_C
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#elif   HW_D
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_D
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#else
    #error "Missing HW"
#endif
```

Macro expansion is set and the hardware variants are defined

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
PREDEFINED             += HW_A
PREDEFINED             += HW_B
PREDEFINED             += ... and so on ...
```

As the output of `doxygen -x <doxyfile>` shows it, the default configuration file has not been modified that much.

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17 (b5fa3cd1c6e6240e20d3b80a70e3f04040b32021)
REPEAT_BRIEF           = NO
LAYOUT_FILE            = testDoxyLayout.xml
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
PREDEFINED            += HW_A
PREDEFINED            += HW_B
PREDEFINED            += HW_C
PREDEFINED            += HW_D
```

Within the documentation, I wish to display every macro once per group.  Therefore, I have to predefined all of them and to authorize doxygen to browse every entry.  This is why I tried to turn the code as follows.  (I do not like it but it seems doxygen requires it)

```
/**
 * \def foo
 * \brief foo is oof
 *
 * \def bar
 * \brief bar is fool
 */
 #ifdef HW_A
 /**
 \addtogroup    HW_A
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#endif

#if HW_B
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_B
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#endif

#if HW_C
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_C
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#endif

#if HW_D
/**
 \addtogroup    HW_D
 @{
 */
    #define foo (1UL)
    #define bar (2UL)
/**
 @}
*/
#endif
```

The output shows multiple definitions for the macros, which is fine, but they all are into the same group (I am guessing the first predefined macro get them all).

[image: Doxygen output]

I have been searching to solve this issue for a long time with no success.  I am assuming, Doxygen is no made to do something like that but I hope one of you will say otherwise :-)

---

Edited: HW_A changed to HW_B, as Albert noticed it
Edited: Full snippet of code

Comment: Which version of doxygen? In your example you add everything to the HW_A group. You try to predefine HW_A and HW_B, but at the same time you have MACRO_EXPANSION=NO. I would at least set MACRO_EXPANSION=YES and for the predefined HW_A I would use HW_A=1 etc.

Comment: Hello Albert,

You are right, this is a mistake in the example here above.  But you have probably already noticed it.

I am running doxygen's version 1.8.17

I confirm it makes no difference with MACRO_EXPANSION=YES and when predefined hardware variants get a value.

Comment: Does this mean that your problem is solved or is there still a problem? In the later case please also try the current version (1.8.20) otherwise please a complete example (You can show the settings different from the default settings by means of `doxygen -x).

Comment: Hello Albert.  No, the issue is not solved.  I am going to ask the sysadmin to update doxygen.  This could take a while.  I will post here as soon as I can tell more on the issue

Comment: Still with version 1.8.17, I started a fresh new project for testing purpose: the example here above + the default doxyfile + the default layout.  I merely enabled the side menu.
Same result: Only HW_A has the macro definitions, other variants have not (which is OK a due to the #if #elif).  The information is not duplicated anymore.  I am now trying to duplicate the definitions: once per group.

Comment: Also complete the issue by means of the used doxygen settings by means of the output of `doxygen -x`

Comment: I see your problem. When using this construct for functions doxygen behaves as you expect (seen as "overloaded" functions), defines are a bit different as they replace the previous setting of the same name. At the moment I don't see a direct possibility to get this correct with `\*group`. Did you have a look at the `\name` command?

Comment: Hello Albert.  Yes, I already tried with ```\name```.  It was not better.  I am slowly coming to the conclusion this cannot be achieved as I thought.  A possible workaround would be to add the information in the root menu entry "modules".  This is not perfect but it is acceptable.